# Why does the result of http request return an empty array?

Tags: axios, httprequest, httpresponse, fetch-api

I've tried using **axios** and **fetch** to get data from an API endpoint, but turns out to have only returned an empty array. It works fine in Postman. What have I missed?

**Using Axios**

```
axios({
        method: "get",
        url: "/api/purchase/receivegoods/index?action=detail-grn",
        params: {
          goods_receive_id: 71,
        },
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
      })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(("response", response));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("error message: ", error.message);
        });
```

**Using Fetch**

```
fetch(
        "https://devactive.com/api/purchase/receivegoods/index?action=detail-grn",
        {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          params: {
            goods_receive_id: 71,
          },
        }
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((result) => {
          console.log("Success:", result);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
```

**EDIT:**
The request is in JSON format. It looks like this (this is an example of an existing id:

```
{
    "goods_receive_id" : 71
}
```

Comment: What does the request you make in Postman look like?

Comment: It's in json format. It only sends an id in json format.

Answer (score 0):

check for possible proxy configuration, postman uses system proxy by default.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the data as the body when using Axios or Fetch. You are hitting the endpoint though. Try something like this:

```js
data = {
  "goods_receive_id" : 71
}

axios({
        method: "get",
        url: "/api/purchase/receivegoods/index?action=detail-grn",
        data: JSON.stringify(data), // <- You add the data to the body here
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
      })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(("response", response));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("error message: ", error.message);
        });
```

or

```js
data = {
  "goods_receive_id" : 71
}
fetch(
        "https://devactive.com/api/purchase/receivegoods/index?action=detail-grn",
        {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          data: JSON.stringify(data), // <- You add the data to the body here
        }
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((result) => {
          console.log("Success:", result);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
```

Comment: I've tried using JSON.stringify. But it doesn't work out.